# Making mixins similar to FabricMC in Rust

Tags: rust, game-development, game-engine

In the Minecraft modding API called [Fabric](https://fabricmc.net/) (and I think most other Minecraft modding APIs) there is a feature called ["mixins"](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:mixin_introduction) which lets you do some things such as:

- Change the internal code of Minecraft by injecting code into function calls or even replacing function calls

```java
@Mixin(TitleScreen.class)
public class ExampleMixin {
    @Inject(at = @At("HEAD"), method = "init()V")
    private void init(CallbackInfo info) {
        System.out.println("This line is printed by an example mod mixin!");
    }
}
```

- Access private variables and call private functions within these mixins

```java
@Mixin(MinecraftClient.class)
public interface MinecraftClientAccessor {
    @Accessor("itemUseCooldown")
    public void setItemUseCooldown(int itemUseCooldown);
}
```

I am making a modding API for a game I am working on. It will contain higher-level stuff like adding custom items to the game which don't require editing the internal code of the game, but I also want the API to be versatile enough that modders can do similar things as they could with Fabric mixins.

As I understand, this requires some kind of reflection behaviour which does not exist in Rust. However, I have seen people emulating reflection-ish things with procedural macros. Would it be possible to make something like Fabric mixins with procedural macros? If so, how? If not, are there any other methods that can achieve something similar to mixins in Rust?

Comment: Is it possible? _Yes_. Is it feasible? Most likely not. At least not to the extent that you desire. Even in your Minecraft example, try and compare Java vs Bedrock modding capabilities. In Bedrock you're overall mostly dealing with resource packs. These are definitely powerful today, but not as powerful as literally injecting code into a jar. All in all, you're better off adding scripting, which is were feasibility comes into the picture. If you want to make everything scriptable, then that's going to require a huge amount of work

Comment: Take a look at [Factorio's Runtime API Docs](https://lua-api.factorio.com/latest/index-runtime.html) for instance. It's very powerful, but it is also not something you _just_ make. Adding on, that you technically want something that's even more powerful than that. That's going to be an absolutely massive undertaking. But it is possible yes

Comment: If you want first-class mod support then you're comparing apples and oranges here. Minecraft has no official mod system; everything out there is third-party, and basically live-patches the running program to achieve the mod functionality. Even the best such mod systems are unsupported hacks that can and do break with new releases. **If you want first-class mod support then you don't want to do what Fabric does.** You want to do something _better._

Comment: Oh that is true. I just thought about the potential use cases for a mixin and realised, that if a mod needs to modify the *internal* code for my game, that probably means either there's something wrong with the modding API or there's something wrong with my game. Minecraft mods like Sodium makes heavy use of mixins because they are there to fix the rendering performance of Minecraft. If I just make everything more or less decent, no one will need to fix anything.